# Like buttons and posting the correct photo on Facebook

Tags: facebook, image, facebook-like, facebook-likebox

I have an online bachelor catalog and I want people to Like a bachelor and have it appear on their FB feed.
http://gothamrfc.org/drupal/?q=2012catalog

I set up the Like button using the Social Plugins feature on FB. All bachelors are on the same page and they have anchors http://gothamrfc.org/drupal/?q=2012catalog#waldmann and the Like button refers to each anchor.

My problem is when the user clicks on Like, it posts the same picture of one bachelor, not of the one that they liked. I didn't see anything in my js file. I also added the og button but that didn't work. 
How do I adjust the code so Like button corresponds to the correct photo?
I'm sure it's something simple. Thank you for your assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Im having the same issue really... My current solution is to hard-code the URL of the image in the like button ref code.
The only issue with this is that it will show that image ONLY, on a blank page when someone clicks the liked image on a user's facebook page.

I'm still looking for answers since the only alternative I've found is to create individual pages for each image (each blog post, in my case) and link to THOSE pages. Not ideal and much more work than I'd like.

have a look at my blog page on my website to see what I mean: [MarinePix Blog](http://www.marinepix.co.uk/blog.html)